# How to create 2 fields that use and change each other's value?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I want to create 2 fields in model namely `field_a`, and `field_b` such that:

- when `field_a`'s value is changed, change value of `field_b` using value of `field_a` in the calculation
- when `field_b`'s value is changed, change value of `field_a` using value of `field_b` in the calculation

I tried using `onchange` on both fields to update each other's value, but it results in a pretty ugly bug that inconsistently updates the values.

I would like to know a solution that works consistently.

Note: Both fields will be used by other fields as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@api.depends` here and define a compute method for each field.

```
field_a = fields.Char()
field_b = fields.Char()

@api.depends('field_b')
def get_updated_value_from_b(self):
    # Your logic to change fields values depending on other
    # assign updated values to your fields
    field_a = new_value_a

@api.depends('field_a')
def get_updated_value_from_a(self):
    # Your logic to change fields values depending on other
    # assign updated values to your fields
    field_b = new_value_b
```

Comment: I added more detail about the changed values. The values are calculation depending on each other's value as well. I tried your code but it is somehow giving inconsistent results similar to what I did. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: Updated my snippet, can you try this?